# How to use the word "petrichor" in a sentence?

Tags: nouns, word-usage

What are the ways in which the word *petrichor* which means scent of the rain, might be used?
Can we use a phrase like "the pleasant petrichor"?

Comment: Actually, it's the scent of rain on dry earth (which I LOVE!).  It wasn't hard to find examples of how to use this interesting word.  Here's one . . .http://www.theyuniversity.net/post/4798167818/how-to-properly-use-petrichor-in-a-sentence

Comment: You'd almost certainly have to define it if you *did* use it. I doubt if 1% of Anglophones would know what you meant otherwise.

Comment: Related: http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/55573/is-petrichor-the-only-noun-in-english-that-means-a-specific-scent

Comment: Usage examples (mostly literal): https://www.google.com/#tbm=bks&q=petrichor&oq=petrichor

Comment: @KristinaLopez that is an example of how not to used the word 'petrichor'

Comment: @Kris I am not asking if it is the only noun for scent.  I am looking for ways the word 'petrichor' can be used. Its no way related to that!

Comment: @FumbleFingers Yes I know many people don't know the meaning of petrichor but I guess we need to use this word so that people look up the dictionary!

Comment: Why do say my linked example is how *not* use the word?  It's a perfectly good example.

Comment: @Kristina: Absolutely! I think that's a brilliant link in the context of this question, given that it's actually titled *How to Properly Use “Petrichor” in a Sentence*.

Comment: @FumbleFingers, thanks, I thought so too which is why the OP's comment confused me. Maybe he meant the other Kris.

Answer (score 4):

I found this sentence in World Wide Words "Besides the pleasant, dewy petrichor of the post-rain afternoon, I see no hope or way out of a four-hour ride with the enigmatic mumbler."  http://www.worldwidewords.org/weirdwords/ww-pet2.htm

Answer (score 1):

This is from the OED:

> "First there is petrichor, the dry smell of unbaked clay, from the Greek for ‘stone-essence’." (L. Forbes, 1999)

It was coined in 1964 out of **petro-** and **ichor**. It isn't so much the scent of rainfall as it is the scent produced when rain falls on rock/ground, or the scent "the first rain after a long period of warm, dry weather". (The smell of wet earth?)

This is what Wikipedia says:

> [The people who coined the word] describe how the smell derives from an oil exuded by certain plants during dry periods, whereupon it is absorbed by clay-based soils and rocks. During rain, the oil is released into the air along with another compound, geosmin, a metabolic by-product of bacteria, which is emitted by wet soil, producing the distinctive scent; ozone may also be present if there is lightning.

EDIT:
@Mitch: You're right, I didn't really answer the question. Since the word was coined so recently, and since there aren't a great many citations in the OED or elsewhere in which the word is actually used in a sentence, I would say that you can pretty much substitute "petrichor" for "the scent of wet earth", etc. in any context: there don't seem to be any subtleties in its meaning.

Comment: This is a good definition, but it doesn't answer the question of the ways the word could be used in a sentence.