# What is the word for "the smell of rain"?

Tags: single-word-requests

I've always noticed that sometimes rain can have a pretty distinct smell.

Do we have a word describing the smell of rain? How can we describe the smell of rain?

"The rain smelt like..."

"The rain had a ... scent."

Comment: This reads more like borderline lit crit than a question about English language and usage. At best it's primarily opinion-based, as I doubt any of us would be able to come to a consensus on what rain smells like.

Comment: Opinion-based. Anyway, it depends what the rain is raining on. On asphalt it has a particular odor. On grass etc. another odor. And if you are a dog then the possibilities are nearly infinite...

Comment: How is this any more opinion-based than any other question about language? There's a word that has, as its very definition, *"a pleasant smell that frequently accompanies the first rain"*. @Drew please explain how this is a matter of opinion? Do you think it's somehow a mere matter of opinion that this word is in the dictionary? There's just no need for nonsense random close voting like this.

Comment: The actual "clean" type smell of the rain or weather system producing the rain that is independent from what the rain is falling is the smell of ozone/trioxygen.

Comment: negative ions being released results in this smell

Comment: The answer of *petrichor* does not mean the "smell of rain" in general. See the definitions given for it. Its meaning is the smell of rain in particular circumstances. And this was exactly why I added my first comment here - rain has multiple smells, depending on the context.

Comment: Unless this question is rewritten, the OP's examples in the question make it POB: "The rain smelt like..." "The rain had a...scent."  The popular answer, "petrichor", does not fit either of those two examples.  Lovely as it is to know there's a word for the smell of rain, that is not what the OP's examples imply.

Comment: There is a book by Magnus Pyke called "Butter Side Up" which includes a chapter on the smell of rain.

Comment: @Drew That's just because OP came up with poor example sentences. The actual question was "Do we have a word describing the smell of rain"? Any word that *specifically* means "the smell of rain" would be tautological in the sentence "the rain smelt like <x>".

Comment: I know some people that work in natural products discovery and culture various [Actinomyces](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Actinomyces) that have the smell of rain.

Comment: @Drew This is about as far from opinion based as it gets; and, furthermore, if you're not familiar with the smell OP is describing (that _very_ _distinct_ smell that a fresh rain can have) then you probably ought to get outdoors a little more often.

Comment: @MετάEd Google brought me here when I was curious about the same thing - and this is exactly where I would have liked it bring me. The whole point behind the Stackexchange sites is to have research-based or more authoritative answers to questions - not just the next guy's opinion from Quora, Yahoo Answers or some blog.

Comment: (4S,4aS,8aR)-4,8a-Dimethyl-1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8-octahydronaphthalen-4a-ol mainly. Nice and easy to scan into poetry, ;-) .

Answer (score 197, accepted):

I'm surprised this question isn't a dupe, and this word has never been offered as an answer to this question before. It's a famous example of a specific word for a specific sensation.

> ### petrichor
>
> /ˈpeˌtrīkôr/
>   noun
>   a pleasant smell that frequently accompanies the first rain after a long period of warm, dry weather.
>   *other than the petrichor emanating from the rapidly drying grass, there was not a trace of evidence that it had rained at all*

This particular definition is from Oxford Dictionaries Online ([ODO](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/us/definition/american_english/petrichor)).

Comment: Snap! You obviously type much faster than me! Or maybe you already knew the word itself (I just knew there *was* a word for it, but I had to actually do the Google search).

Comment: Here's an adjectival usage... [*she'll put up new shoots and afterwards relish **the petrichoral scent***](https://myriorama.wordpress.com/)

Comment: @FumbleFingers Umm. That particular word appears to have been coined as recently as 1964, by some Australians who were seeking to describe the effects of rain on a region hitherto long subjected to drought. Sounds like a scientific term to me, which may or may not be applicable in all conditions. It refers to plants which deposit oil, of which Australia is naturally replete - the most inflammable country on earth. The surprising fact is that there seems to be no word which the likes of Shakespeare would have used for this condition.

Comment: *Thy love is like the petrichor...*, no, I definitely don't think it works!

Comment: @WS2 I don't know actually, it does have a kind of poetic quality to it...though it does sound a bit like a mythical beast. Jabberwocky vs Petrichor: coming soon to a cinema near you!

Comment: @WS2 If instruction by an English teacher is any indication of the validity of a word use, I had been given this word in English class to describe the smell of rain.  In my part of the world (Arizona), our smell of rain is derived from the cresote bush directly, not from any oils delivered to the earth itself.  That's an indication that at least some individuals use petrichor in the  non-scientific sense ODO used it.

Comment: @Cort Ammon *Petrichor* sounds like some toxic, viscous hydrocarbon to me. It certainly doesn't suggest the delicate fragrance of new fallen rain on grass.

Comment: I agree with @WS2, though this is the correct word, it's not what OP is likely looking for and why this question becomes one that is primarily opinion based.

Comment: Never hear of Petrichor. Apparently it's the odor of **Geosmin** (4S,4aS,8aR)-4,8a-Dimethyl-1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8-octahydronaphthalen-4a-ol which I have heard of: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geosmin

Comment: Just thought I'd add a little etymology to the word petrichor. Petr- is the standard prefix for "stone". Ichor is the Greek word for the blood of the gods. This word was the Greek way of saying the essence or innate smell of stone which was brought out by the rain.

Comment: "petrichor emanating from the rapidly drying grass" - does that mean the smell is coming from the *grass* as it is drying after the rain, instead of coming from the rain as it is falling, like the asker is asking?

Comment: @ZackT. The OP is not asking after the smell of water.

Comment: That's fairly recent word

Comment: @Prashant Pfff, just because Google NGram Viewer doesn't have any entries before 1968 doesn't mean the word is... hey, wait a minute.

Comment: The asker would have known this if he watched Doctor Who. ;)
http://tardis.wikia.com/wiki/Petrichor

Answer (score 65):

While *petrichor* is the fabulous word that describes the perceived smell, it may also be helpful to know that ***geosmin*** is the word that describes the distinctive aromatic source of this smell:

From wikipedia (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geosmin)

> *Geosmin* is an organic compound with a distinct earthy flavor and aroma produced by a type of Actinobacteria, and is responsible for the earthy taste of beets and a contributor to the strong scent (*petrichor*) that occurs in the air when rain falls after a dry spell of weather or when soil is disturbed.[1] In chemical terms, it is a bicyclic alcohol with formula C12H22O, a derivative of decalin. **Its name is derived from the Greek γεω- "earth" and ὀσμή "smell".**

Comment: Interesting. Yesterday I read in my local newspaper (or was it the NYT?) that geosmin was produced by Streptomyces, a bit more specific attribution and also the source of one of the earliest forms of antibiotics.

Answer (score 28):

Interestingly enough (and thanks to a bit of Googling), there is a specific word for the smell accompanying rain — *petrichor*. Essentially what you smell is whatever combination of primarily oils, bacterial spores, ground-detritus, and ozone is present in the air and on the ground, and which was stirred about and released into the air when the rain came.

Definition:
*That distinctively pleasant fragrance of rain falling on dry ground. It is produced by oily, yellow-gold globules, rather like perfume, that come either from certain plants or the air itself.* (Alpha Dictionary)

Example Sentence:
*It's been raining for several days this week but our noses can't smell the petrichor because our showers are falling on saturated ground, ice filled pools, and grey piles of our most recent snowstorm's remnants.* (Oxford Dictionaries)

(source -- http://www.smithsonianmag.com/science-nature/what-makes-rain-smell-so-good-13806085/?no-ist)

Comment: +1 for pointing out that it is not actually the rain that has a smell, but the *stuff* that the rain brings out.  (Let's all sing along now:  We are the worms, out on the pavement...)

Comment: +1 for explaining what it is rather than just copy pasting a dictionary definition

Comment: and I just thought it was ozone.....